# how to implement components made using storybook and react in another real application using github repo link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uikit, storybook, nextjs-storybook

**Importing storybook components to another project**

how to implement components made using storybook and react in another real application using github repo link ?

by using github-repo link i need to import the storybook into another project

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough to be able to answer it, but check to see if the design system (sounds like it's a design system) has instructions in its readme to use `npm install` or `yarn add`. If it's your own design system, you'll first need to publish it to NPM https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/introduction-to-packages-and-modules

Answer (score 0):

basically in case of private projects you want to add a storybook via repo link, THE ANSWER is you simply execute this command in your terminal:

yarn add "your-repo-https-link" or npm install "your-repo-https-link"

but before doing this make sure your storybook builds properly and has no issue otherwise the project that using this package is going to break.